# Upgrade to laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, macros, laravel-5

I upgraded to Laravel 5.0, 70% of the Application is working, but I have problems with the login. I have macros -> html::macro and response::macro. The html::macro is working - I use html::macros for navigation. But if I need an response::macro, I get this error:

```
exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Method ajaxRedirect does not exist.'
```

Here is my call:

```
public function postAuthenticate()
{
    try
    {
        $this->service->authenticate(Input::except(['_token', 'extended']));
    }
    catch(AuthenticationNotValidException $ex)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationNotValidAjaxException($ex->getMessage());
    }

    if (Session::has('tempRequest'))
    {
        $this->service->addTemporaryRequest(Auth::user());
    }

    return Response::ajaxRedirect(route(
        (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) ? 'admin.dashboard' : 'customer.dashboard'));
}
```

And here the Macro:

```
Response::macro('ajaxRedirect', function($url)
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'state'     => true,
        'redirect'  => $url
    ));
});
```

why I got this error, do I miss something? In Laravel 4 everything was working fine. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: When returning the response, try `return response()->ajaxRedirect(route(
            (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) ? 'admin.dashboard' : 'customer.dashboard'
        ));`

Comment: Thank you. I've already tried, but it ends in the same error.

Comment: Are you sure whichever file you are setting up that macro in is being loaded at some point before you are trying to use it?

Comment: The response::makro is in the same file as the html::makro and is loeaded. Under "app->providers" I added a file MacroServiceProvider, which is loading the macros as a provider like in this post: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/50-loading-form-macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References:

- [Response Macros](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#response-macros)
- [Service Providers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers)

---

Here is the way to go to make custom/macro [laravel-5](/questions/tagged/laravel-5) response

#### Create your service provider

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ResponseMacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Response::macro('ajaxRedirect', function($url)
        {
            return Response::json(array(
                'state'     => true,
                'redirect'  => $url
            ));
        });
    }

}
```

and save it as `ResponseMacroServiceProvider.php` in `app/Providers`.

#### Update accordingly the providers list

```
<?php

return [
    
    ...
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */
    
    'providers' => [
        
        ...
        
        'App\Providers\ResponseMacroServiceProvider',
    ],

    ...
```

in `config/app.php`.

#### Enjoy

You should be able to use it in your controller

```
return Response::ajaxRedirect(route(
    (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) ? 'admin.dashboard' : 'customer.dashboard'));
```

as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! You had just one little typo (ResponseMacroServiceProvider and ResponseServiceProvider) and missed the public function register() { } in the ResponseMacroServiceProvider. But now i'm happy! Thx!